# opendaylight development tutorial using fluorine?

Tags: opendaylight

I'm completely new to opendaylight and I'm trying to develop a new feature. I've tried following multiple examples but they all seem out-of-date as many of the classes and methods used are deprecated. (Example: they all use the onSessionCreate() method which it appears has been replaced with the start() method.) I would like to use Fluorine v0.9.1 because it comes packaged with the openflowplugin (which I need). Are there any tutorials I can follow that are up-to-date for fluorine? I'm really struggling to understand opendaylight and having constant build errors is just making it worse.

A tutorial I tried: https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-fluorine/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html?highlight=developing%20apps

Thanks you!

Comment: The startup archetype outlined in the docs link above should be up-to-date and provide a good starting point. What issues are you encountering with the Fluorine startup archetype?

Comment: The actual example has a DataBroker but the tutorial does not use it. It seems necessary. Just from programming experience, it looks like the onSessionInitiated() method was replaced with the start() method. ProviderContext is deprecated. I don't remember what the error was but I had build errors with the HelloWorldImpl class. At that point I gave up.

Comment: and also, I couldn't pull version 1.0.0. Had to pull 1.1.0

Comment: Unfortunately that example is out-of-date. The archetype now uses Blueprint for wiring instead of ProviderContext etc.

Comment: So do you know of an up-to-date example? Seems silly that I haven't been able to find one

Comment: Unfortunately that tends to happen in open source - folks come and go and things get out-of-date or abandoned etc. The only one I know of that has been kept pretty up-to-date is https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Toaster_Step-By-Step